# Similarity of matrices implying unitary similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

if we consider the following question;

> $A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ are Hermitian. Show that $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if $A$ and $B$ are unitarily similar.

My solution, which I am unsure whether it is correct or not, is as follows

**Assuming $A$ and $B$ are unitarily similar,**
$$
A = U^*BU \implies A = U^{-1}BU
$$
as $U$ is unitary. Therefore, $A$ and $B$ are similar.

---

**Assuming $A$ and $B$ are similar**,

$$
A = S^{-1}BS \hspace{1cm}\text{and}\hspace{1cm} A^* = S^*B^*(S^{-1})^*
$$

Due to that fact that $A = A^*$,

$$
\begin{align}
&\implies S^{-1}BS = S^*B^*(S^{-1})^*\\
&\implies B = SS^*B^*(S^{-1})^*(S^{-1})
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, since $B = B^*$,

$$
SS^* = I\\
(S^{-1})^*(S^{-1}) = I
$$
we have that $S$ is unitary.

$$
A = S^{-1}BS = S^*BS
$$

Concluding that $A$ and $B$ are unitarily similar.

---

Any clarification would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your “therefore” for $B$ does not follow. Just because $B=B^*$, this does not mean that if $B=TB^*T^{-1}$, then $T=I$ and $T^{-1}=I$. For example, you could have $SS^*=kI$ and $(S^{-1})^*(S^{-1})=\frac{1}{k}I$ for some constant $k\neq 1,0$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim $SS^* = I$ is not true.

Consider linear map $A$ which sends orthonormal vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ to $\lambda_1 v_1,\lambda_1v_2,\lambda_3 v_3$, A is hermitian since it is orthogonally (unitarily) diagonalisable.

Let $B=A$, write diagonalisation of $A,B$ as follows,

$A=[v_1+v_2 \  v_2\   v_3][\lambda_1 e_1,\lambda_1e_2,\lambda_3 e_3][v_1+v_2\  v_2 \ v_3]^{-1}$

Now $S=[v_1+v_2 \  v_2\   v_3]$, $SS^*\neq I$, this is proven by considering as follows

$S$ under some change of basis, is then $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0  \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
0&0&1
  \end{bmatrix}
$, hence the product is not the identity.

One solution is that, if $A,B$ similar, they have same eigenvalues, since both are Hermetian, they are unitarily diagonalisable, giving the solution.